# errors while installing dependencies using npm install

Tags: npm

I am going to install dependencies in my project using npm install. It gives error of unable to resolve dependency tree. but when I run the same command on other system, it works fine and install all the dependencies. I got this error:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! While resolving: client-v1@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: zone.js@0.10.3
npm ERR! node_modules/zone.js
npm ERR!   zone.js@"~0.10.1" from the root project
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer zone.js@"~0.9.1" from @angular/core@8.2.14
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/core
npm ERR!   @angular/core@"~8.2.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular/core@"8.2.14" from @angular/animations@8.2.14
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/animations
npm ERR!     @angular/animations@"^8.2.1" from the root project
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

This is my package.json file:

```
    "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^8.2.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.1.2",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.1",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.1",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^8.0.0-beta.26",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.1",
    "@angular/material": "^8.1.2",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^8.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.1",
    "@angular/pwa": "~0.802.1",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.1",
    "@angular/service-worker": "~8.2.1",
    "@azure/msal-angular": "^1.1.2",
    "@contentful/rich-text-html-renderer": "^13.4.0",
    "@contentful/rich-text-types": "^13.4.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^5.3.1",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^8.2.0",
    "@ngrx/entity": "^8.2.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^8.2.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "amazon-cognito-identity-js": "^3.0.15",
    "angular-calendar": "^0.28.22",
    "angular2-hotkeys": "^2.1.5",
    "apollo-angular": "^1.8.0",
    "apollo-angular-link-http": "^1.9.0",
    "apollo-cache-inmemory": "^1.6.5",
    "apollo-client": "^2.6.4",
    "apollo-link": "^1.2.13",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
    "contentful": "^7.11.1",
    "core-js": "^3.2.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.16.1",
    "elasticlunr": "^0.9.5",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "google-libphonenumber": "^3.2.3",
    "graphql": "^14.4.2",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.10.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "lodash.sumby": "^4.6.0",
    "lunr-languages": "^1.4.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "moment-range": "^4.0.2",
    "msal": "^1.4.4",
    "ng2-charts": "^2.3.2",
    "ngx-color": "^4.1.1",
    "ngx-international-phone-number": "^1.0.4",
    "ngx-mask": "^8.0.3",
    "ngx-spinner": "^8.0.3",
    "ngx-swiper-wrapper": "^8.0.2",
    "ngx-toastr": "^10.0.4",
    "numeral": "^2.0.6",
    "pdfmake": "^0.1.58",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.2",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.2",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^3.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.1"
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you